# @Transactional annotation does not proxy my class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have 3 classes, AccountController, AccountManager and AccountDao (they're injected to one another in that order, i.e controller <- manager <- dao). When I put a @Transactional annotation on accountDao, I have a DB session and everything works fine. when I put the @Transactional on the manager, it does not work. I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

I see that accountManager is not wrapper with a proxy for some reason (when debugging). Any ideas why this happens?

In my application context's XML I have:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" use-default-filters="true">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

On AccountManager I put the following annotations:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class AccountManager  { ... }
```

And the even weirder thing is, AccountManager has a 'DeviceManager' injected into it, with the same annotations as AccountManager but DeviceManager does get proxied! It is fully transactional.

I am using the org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional annotation.

I do not have any final methods in AccountManager

Comment: Shot in the dark - you are using the same `@Transactional`? You didn't import a different one by accident?

Comment: show us the `hibernateTransactionManager` bean definition and also does  `AccountManager` have any `final` methods by any chance ?

Comment: I'm using the correct @Transactional annotation, same one I used in AccountDao (org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)

Comment: The hibernateTransactionManager is a simple bean that does work for other classes, just not for AccountManager for some reason. It's simply: <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

Comment: well, there are few things I might suggest you to try: 1) replace `@Repository` with `@Service` annotation, since it's definitely not a Repository. 2) When you Autowire your class do it by Interface, not a Class 3) Check that the method you call is public.

Comment: Ok, this one's pretty old, but I faced the same issue, and figured that the bean in question had a property injection as well, because of which an un-proxied bean got injected to the other beans.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to echo @Enigo's answer:

1. `AccountManager` is not a repository, so it should be annotated with `@Service` and the `AccountDao` should be annotated with `@Repository`
2. `AccountManager` should implement an interface and that interface should be injected into the Controller class
3. Ensure the method you're calling within `AccountManager` is public and overrides the method declaration in the interface

Comment: I would agree with you if my other classes weren't proxied. But again, AccountDao works fine when I add @Transactional on it